# add full screen image to mp4 by ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

i want to add a 1920 x 1080 image to 720p and 1080p video from 0 to 5 second (source will be different resolution)  and add another image same resoltion to second 10to15 second and another image to 20 to 25 socond

i used

```
ffmpeg -i 1080.mp4 -i id1.png -i id2.png -i id3.png -map_metadata -1
-s hd720  -c:v  h264 \
-crf 26 \
-c:a aac -b:a 128k -strict -2 \
-preset veryfast \
-filter_complex \ "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,5)' [tmp]; \ [tmp][2:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,10,15)'[tmp];\
[tmp][3:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,20,25)'" \ 720p.mp4
```

issue is source size i dont know how to use `scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih*1.0` in my code

Comment: Many examples if you search `[ffmpeg] is:answer scale2ref`

Comment: i searched before but i did not find right way
 i just need scale 3 different images in 3 diffent times on video

Answer (score 0):

Use the [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i 1080.mp4 -i id1.png -i id2.png -i id3.png -map_metadata -1 -c:v h264 -crf 26 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -preset veryfast -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-2:720[ref1];[1][ref1]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih[id1][ref2];[2][ref2]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih[id2][ref3];[3][ref3]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih[id3][bg];[bg][id1]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,5)'[bg2];[bg2][id2]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,10,15)'[bg3];[bg3][id3]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,20,25)'" -movflags +faststart 720p.mp4
```

Comment: you are perfect ♥️